# Buying bitcoins with a credit card without the charges being applied as a cash advance

Tags: buy-bitcoins, bitcoin-credit-card

How or where can I buy bitcoins with a credit card without it being applied to the card as a cash advance? I read the company selling the bitcoins (Coinmama, Coinbase, etc) lists what type of transaction is being made and that's how the type of transaction is determined (i.e. regular purchase or cash advance). Is that true and if so could the bitcoin company control what the transaction appears as? In other words is it possible at one website (for example Coinmama) the purchase would appear as a cash advance and at another website it would appear as a regular purchase?